# Email send through Zend not working

Tags: magento-enterprise

```
 $mail = new zend_Mail();
 $mail->setFrom('test@gmail.com','martal');
 $mail->addTo('test1@gmail.com', 'kelvin');
 $mail->setSubject("test mail functionality");
 try{
    $mail->send();  
 }catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMesssage();
 }
```

I use the above for sending mail but it's not working.
I couldn't find any error in exception.log also hasn't got any message in cache 
Also, I run the cron.php no use with it.
But could get order confirmation mail etc..

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct since there is some issue in server the mail was not yet send